# How to add action bar menu from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

i have following action bar menu file:

**Menu file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuitem_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="List of planed calls">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuitem_send"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Add new call">
</item>
```

**In fragment i have following code:**

```
public class Fragment_CallPlanningWeek extends Fragment {

public Fragment_CallPlanningWeek(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_planning_week, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.call_planning, menu);
}
```

}

Problem is that menu in not visible in action bar on given fragment.

How can i solve it please?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: well a fragment does not have an actionbar, an activity does. so if you want to display a new set of menu options you need to change the menu in your hosting activity

Answer (score 0):

When creating your fragment call:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: I added setHasOptionsMenu(true); into onCreateView method in fragment but without any change.